# Pass arguments from fragment to another activity

Tags: android

I'm using the navigation controller for navigating. I need to navigate from the current fragment to a different activity and pass it some data. This has been problematic. Navigating to the activity works but the arguments are null. Here is the global action I am using in my navigation graph:

```
<action android:id="@+id/sign_out"
        app:destination="@id/login_activity">

    <argument
            android:name="clearSession"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>

</action>

<activity android:id="@+id/login_activity"
          android:name="com.example.ui.login.LoginActivity"
          android:label="loginActivity">

    <argument
            android:name="clearSession"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>

</activity>
```

And the menu navigation item:

```
<item android:title="@string/app">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                    android:id="@+id/sign_out"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app"
                    android:title="@string/sign_out"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Code for setting up navigation:

```
navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.connections_fragment, R.id.search_fragment), drawerLayout)

// Set up ActionBar
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)


// Set up navigation menu
binding.navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

I'm using a navigation drawer and a menu item in the navigation view has its id set to "sign_out". Clicking on this menu item will cause the Login screen to be loaded but the arguments are not provided even though they are specified in both the action and the destination. The navigation controller does not appear to be sending the arguments when it launches the Login activity and I suspect that this is a bug in Android. There are virtually no posts in Stackoverflow showing users passing data from a fragment to a different activity.

Comment: Try using Interfaces.

Comment: use lifecycle observers or rx or eventbus

Comment: @glucaio I updated my post to show the code used to setup navigation in the activity. There really is no navigation code. All I'm doing is binding the navigation view to the navigation controller.

Comment: @glucaio Could you please post your code as a solution so that I can see how you got it to work. Would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your sign_out action inside `<fragment>` tag?
If so you can call use navigate() method:

```
  val bundle = Bundle().apply { putString("EXTRA_KEY", "EXTRA_VALUE") }
  findNavController().navigate(R.id.sign_out, bundle)
```

And then `val stringExtra = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY")` in LoginActivity

Comment: No it's a global action. It really doesn't matter if it's inside or outside a fragment. When you bind the navigation view to the navigation controller, you have no access to the navigation menu items. The navigation controller takes over and performs the navigation. Actually, you can intercept the menu item clicks if the navigation is to a fragment in the current navigation graph. But you cannot intercept it if the menu item navigates to a different activity. So there is no way to use your code. This is increasingly starting to look like a bug in the navigation controller.